# Pascal, finding all the ways between 2 graph nodes

Tags: graph, pascal

I was working at PascalABC.Net program about finding all the ways between two points (graph nodes). Each point is labeled with a number. The graph is described this way: in the root folder there are folders with points' numbers. Each contains only a file 'info.txt' where the number of points with which the current point is connected.

The program should work this way: a user writes the number of all points (it is used during the calculation, `var nopall`), the number of the start point (`var nosp`) and the number of the finish point (`var nofp`). The program takes this information and connects to the smallest point that is connected with the current points. It also checks for repeats (they shouldn't occur). But the problem is it doesn't finds all the ways, it just change the last point and starts to look for a new ways from it. What should I do for it working as I planned?

```
program buildway;

var
paw: uint64; 
nopall: uint64;
nosp: uint64;
nofp: uint64;
lastpoint: uint64;  
wayfiletxt: text;
wayfilestr: string;
mapdir: string;
infotxt: text;
infostr: string;
connection: boolean;
pastpoint: uint64;

label start, check;

begin
  //user writes the var
  writeln('nop(all), nosp, nofp');
  readln(nopall);
  readln(nosp);
  readln(nofp);
//
  mapdir := GetDir;
  wayfilestr := IntToStr(nosp);
  lastpoint := nosp;
  paw := paw + 1;
  start:

  if lastpoint = nofp then
  begin
  ChDir(mapdir);
  Assign(wayfiletxt, 'way.txt');
  Append(wayfiletxt);
  Writeln(wayfiletxt, wayfilestr);
  Close(wayfiletxt);
  while
  WayfileStr[Length(WayfileStr)] <> '/'
    do
    SetLength(WayFileStr, Length(Wayfilestr) - 1); 
  SetLength(WayFileStr, Length(Wayfilestr) - 1); 
  if
  paw = nopall
    then
    paw := 0;
  paw := paw + 1;
 lastpoint := pastpoint;
 goto start;

 end;

 if paw = nosp
then
  begin
  paw := paw + 1;
  goto start;
  end;

connection := False;

while paw <= nopall
do
begin

//it's cheking for repeats
if
Pos(IntToStr(paw), '/' + wayfilestr + '/') <> 0
then    
begin
  paw := paw + 1;
  goto start;
end;  
  //
  //and there's cheking for connection
ChDir(mapdir);
ChDir(IntToStr(lastpoint));
Assign(infotxt, 'info.txt');
Reset(infotxt);
Read(infotxt, infostr);
begin
  check:
  if
  Pos('{' + paw + '}', infostr) = 0
      then
    while
    seekeof(infotxt) = False
      do
    begin
      readln(infotxt, infostr);
      goto check;
    end;
  if
  Pos('{' + paw + '}', infostr) <> 0
      then
    connection := True;
end;
Close(infotxt);
  //
  //variant 1
if connection = True then
begin
  wayfilestr := wayfilestr + '/' + paw;
  pastpoint := lastpoint;
  lastpoint := paw;
  if paw <> nofp
    then
    paw := 1;
  goto start;
end;
  //
  //variant 2
if connection = False then
begin
  paw := paw + 1;
  goto start;
end;  
//
end;
end.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to clarify the algorithm after "The program takes this information and connects ...", it is not quite clear.

Comment: @YakovL Thanks for helping me tranclate my minds from Russian to English. By "smallest  point" I meant the point with smallest number from all list of points that is connected with current point.

Comment: Separate your program into functional parts - user input, graph reading and building graph data structure in the memory, finding all the ways. Check that all stages (procedures) work well. Current code is not readable.